# How to write query on cloud firestore to get documents?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular8

[image]

I want to fetch all devices (documents as you can see on the image) where its collection email field matched to **asad12@gmail.com** address.
how I can do this with angular firebase?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did not try yet, I have search a lot on google but did not get a specific way for this scenario.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on how to make Firestore queries in an Angular app.  I suggest reviewing that documentation, making an attempt on your own, and post the code that doesn't work the way you expect. https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}
const docRef = this.afs.doc('users/list');
const deviceRef = docRef.collection('devices', ref => ref.where('email', '==', 'asad12@gmail.com')).valueChanges();
```

using `where()` you can query according to the value of the email. `valueChanges()` returns an Observable which you can subscribe using the method `subscribe()` to receive the data.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md

Comment: its working, thankyou.

Comment: it was mistakenly clicked on the checkmark. it has checked again